# Getting a planet's speed to scale with the inverse square of it's distance?

Tags: javascript, orbital-mechanics

Following this [excellent tutorial](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/generating-svg-solar-systems-part-1-setting-the-scene/) on making a procedural solar system, and so far it's coming along nicely. My only problem with it is that the orbit speeds aren't as accurate as I'd like. I want the orbital periods to follow Kepler's Third Law. Only problem is that I don't know how to get it to work like that.

Here is the code related to the orbits. How do I get it to work how I want it to?

```js
function drawPlanet(size, distance) {
  const hue = randomInt(0, 360);
  const saturation = randomInt(70, 100);
  const lightness = randomInt(50, 70);
  const color = `hsl(${hue}, ${saturation}%, ${lightness}%)`;

  return `
    <circle 
      cx="${width / 2 + distance}" 
      cy="${height / 2}" 
      r="${size}" 
      fill="${color}"
      class="planet"
      style="
        --start-rotation:${randomInt(0, 0)}deg;
        --rotation-speed:${distance * randomInt(40, 70)}ms;
      "
    />
  `;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of the tutorial here. I'm glad you enjoyed it!

This is a good question. I'm not an expert on astronomy or mathematics, but I'll do my best to answer.

**Setting Speed Via Custom Property**

The first thing to know is that the rotation speed is controlled by the `--rotation-speed` custom property. We'll be updating that value from `distance * randomInt(40, 70)` to a more accurate value. Right now this is set in milliseconds.

So we need to determine what value to set that custom property to.

**Non-scientific caveats**

I'm going to be taking a couple short-cuts in my math here:

- Kepler's law has complex math to account for the fact that most orbits are elliptical (not circular). My tutorial is using circular orbits, which makes the match simpler. (For an additional challenge you could try switching to elliptical orbits)
- Obviously real-life orbits are too slow for us to observe, so we'll need to speed them up, but make them more realistic in relation to eachother.

**Determining a more accurate speed**

With those caveats in mind, let's find a formula we can use. I found this helpful article which describes how to calculate circular orbital speeds: https://www.nagwa.com/en/explainers/142168516704/

Here's a JS approximation of the formula they outline in the article:

```js
function velocity(gravitationalConstant, starMass, orbitDistance) {
  return Math.sqrt((gravitationalConstant * starMass) / orbitDistance);
}
```

This just gets us the velocity though. To set the animation speed we need to know how long the entire orbit will take. We could figure this out by determining the circumference of the orbit, and comparing that to the velocity. Here's how we can get the orbit circumference:

```js
function circumference(radius) {
  const diameter = radius * 2;
  return Math.PI * diameter;
}
```

We can do something similar in the `drawPlanet` function:

```js
function drawPlanet(size, distance) {
  const hue = randomInt(0, 360);
  const saturation = randomInt(70, 100);
  const lightness = randomInt(50, 70);
  const color = `hsl(${hue}, ${saturation}%, ${lightness}%)`;

  
  // Since we're only worried about _relative_ orbit speeds we can set 
  // this to whatever we like
  const gravitationalConstant = 1;
  // We could pass the size of the star into our function and use 
  // that to generate a star mass if we'd like.
  // Then the orbit speeds would differ based on the star size.
  // For now, let's hard code it.
  const starMass = 1;
  // We already know the orbit distance, so we have the radius.
  const orbitRadius = distance;

  // Apply our formulas
  const velocity = Math.sqrt((gravitationalConstant * starMass) / orbitRadius);
  const orbitCircumference = Math.PI * orbitRadius * 2;

  // Compare the velocity to the orbit circumference to find the duration
  // of a single orbit
  const orbitDuration = orbitCircumference / velocity;

  return `
    <circle 
      cx="${width / 2 + distance}" 
      cy="${height / 2}" 
      r="${size}" 
      fill="${color}"
      class="planet"
      style="
        --start-rotation:${randomInt(0, 0)}deg;
        --rotation-speed:${orbitDuration}ms;
      "
    />
  `;
}
```

Here's [a codepen](https://codepen.io/phebert/pen/dyZExgb?editors=0010) showing it in action. As I mentioned above, I'm no astronomer, but I think this should point you in the right direction. Happy coding!

Comment: Holy crap, thank you. Never thought I'd get an answer from the author!

Comment: @Titanic sure thing, I hope this helps! Feel free to reach out further if you have other questions.

Comment: So I came back to this to try and make the star mass depend on the size, with my equation for calculating it in mind being (star-size^2 / 95^2)^3
 So I put this into the line for star mass: (((starSize ^ 2) / 9025) ^ 3)
The screen only shows a black box after putting that in, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey @Titanic it's hard to say without more info. Were there any errors in the dev tools console? If you put together a codepen I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Here's the code pen: [link](https://codepen.io/inky-bendy/pen/jOYvbay)

Comment: Hey @Titanic, it looks like `starSize` is not defined where you're trying to access it. (You can see the error in the Codepen console)

I added a `starSize` parameter to the `drawPlanet` function and passed the star's size into the function. I think this Codepen should fix your issue: https://codepen.io/phebert/pen/mdpGYvj?editors=0010

Comment: It did fix it, thank you so much!

Comment: @Titanic, awesome, I'm glad to hear it!